# ORBEON Forms - how to use the Profiler

Tags: orbeon

Can anybody share some detailed steps on `how to configure the profiler`, and how to see the results. It seems that using `/profiler/xpl/` or `/tools-profiler/xpl/` gives the same error:

```
Cannot load "/apps/profiler/page-flow.xml" with webapp loader
```

Answer (score 0):

The XPL profiler has been removed since Orbeon Forms 3.9. You can still find its [source code](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/tree/master/src/resources/apps/xforms-attic/tools-profiler) in the "attic", in case you're interested in reviving it, but it isn't currently part of Orbeon Forms and there are no plans to take it out of the attic.